# How to Prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\rightarrow0 $ iff $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2\rightarrow0 $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that each  $a_n\in (0,1)$.

prove that  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\rightarrow0 $ iff $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2\rightarrow0 $.

I don't have a clear idea about how to prove this yet I tried like this,

$a_n \in (0,1)\implies a_n^2\leq a_n$  $ \forall n\in N$

form this by some manipulation and by  comparison we can obtain the first implication i don't know how to proceed further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\implies :$ If $a_n\in]0,1[$, then $0<a_n^2<a_n$ and thus
$$0<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}^2<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\implies ...$$

$\Longleftarrow:$ Using Cauchy-Schwarz on $$\sum_{k}1\cdot a_k$$
i.e.
$$\sum_{k}a_k b_k\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k}{a_k}^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k}b_k^2}$$

and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

- We will first prove that if $\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}a_k \to 0 $,then $\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}a_k^2 \to 0$. Since $a_k \in (0,1)$, we have $a_k^2 < a_k$. Hence, $$0 < \dfrac{\sum_{k \leq n}a_k^2}n < \dfrac{\sum_{k \leq n}a_k}n \to 0$$
- We will now prove that if $\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}a_k^2 \to 0 $,then $\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}a_k \to 0$. By Cauchy Schwarz, we have
  $$0 < \sum_{k \leq n}a_k \cdot 1 \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k \leq n}a_k^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k \leq n}1} \implies 0 < \dfrac{\sum_{k \leq n}a_k}n \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{k \leq n}a_k^2}n} \to 0$$